# how we change constraint of image programatically?

Tags: swift

Here is what I done, But it does not work! I do not have any idea right now for fixing the issue. any idea?

the error:

imageConstraints[2301:119390] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
Try this:
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000000dc640 UIImageView:0x7fe150709680.width == 50   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000000e23f0 UIImageView:0x7fe150709680.width == 250   (active)>"
)

```
import UIKit

var imageV = UIImageView()


class ViewController: UIViewController
{

    
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
       
        super.viewDidLoad()

        
        imageV.image = UIImage(systemName: "1.circle")
        imageV.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)

        view.addSubview(imageV)
        imageV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageV.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        imageV.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        imageV.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        imageV.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -200).isActive = true
        
   
    }

    
    @IBAction func newConstraintsButton_Action(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        
        
       
        

        imageV.removeFromSuperview()
        view.addSubview(imageV)
        imageV.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 250)
        imageV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        
        imageV.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = false
        imageV.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = false
        imageV.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
        imageV.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
        imageV.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        imageV.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -200).isActive = true
        
        
        

    }
    
}
```

Comment: What have you done? What does not work? What issue?

Comment: Button Action does not change the constraint of image! I like that happen!

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the `imageV` inside `ViewController`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var imageV = UIImageView()
    //...
}
```